# Can you use ES2015+ features (ES6) in Adobe XD plugins?

Tags: plugins, require, adobe-xd

I'm building a plugin in Adobe XD. Can I use ES2015+ (ES6) features? For example, template literals, `let` , `const`, Arrow functions, asynchronous functions ( async / await )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XD plugin APIs support most of ES2015 and beyond. You can use features such as:

- Template literals
- Classes
- Block-scoped variables ( `let` , `const` )
- Object destructuring
- Default parameters
- Spread and Rest ( `...` )
- Arrow functions
- Asynchronous functions ( `async` / `await` )
- Promises

You can also use ES5 JavaScript features as well.

The XD plugin API docs have a page on [JavaScript support](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/javascript/javascript-support.html).